# Как получить данные из файла конфигурации при регистрации зависимостей?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, di, autofac

подскажите пожалуйста, как получить данные из файла конфигурации при регистрации зависимостей? В качестве Ioc-контейнера использую Autofac.

Имеется следующий блок в файле конфигурации

```
"Jwt": {
"Key": "SecretKey10125779374235322",
"Issuer": "https://localhost:44396",
"Audience": "http://localhost:5000"
```

}

Имеется абстракции и реализация для генерации токена.

```
public interface IJwtGenerator
{
    string CreateToken(string login);
}

public class JwtGenerator : IJwtGenerator
{
    private readonly SymmetricSecurityKey _key;

    private readonly string _issuer;

    private readonly string _audience;

    public JwtGenerator(IConfiguration config)
    {
        _key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(config["Jwt:Key"]));
        _issuer = config["Jwt:Issuer"];
        _audience = config["Jwt:Audience"];
    }

    public string CreateToken(string userName)
    {
        var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

        var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
        {
            Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new[] {new Claim("UserName", userName)}),
            Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(7),
            Issuer = _issuer,
            Audience = _audience,
            SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(_key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
        };

        var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
        return tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);
    }
}


public class SecurityModule : Module
{
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.RegisterType<JwtGenerator>()
            .As<IJwtGenerator>()
            .WithParameter()
    }
}
```

Как сделать регистрацию этого модуля?

Comment: Я так понимаю речь идет про `IConfiguration`? Если да, то где он в вашем коде? Вы должны через конструктор его передать (`public JwtGenerator(IConfiguration config){...}`), а дальше забрать от туда все необходимое простым `config["Jwt:Key"]`, все, остальную работу за вас сделает контейнер, вам лишь зарегистрировать надо тип и в конфиг файл (`appsettings.json`) прописать все необходимое. И да, зачем вам Autofac в asp.net проекте, который имеет свой контейнер..? И да, секретны хранятся иначе...

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, я обновил вопрос, всё-равно не понимаю как зарегистрировать этот файл конфигурации)

Comment: У меня есть идея прокинуть IConfiguration в конструктор модуля, но тогда у меня не получится зарегистрировать все модули вот этот строкой:             containerBuilder.RegisterAssemblyModules(typeof(Startup).Assembly);

Comment: Вы ведь понимаете, что сейчас говорите про то, о чем изначально нам (сообществу) неизвестно. Вы говорите так, будто мы сидим у вас за спиной и видим все то, что вы делаете, весь ваш код. Сейчас я лишь знаю: "asp.net", "добавил в проект AutoFac (замена стандартного или отдельно?)", "Хочет IConfiguration внедрить в класс для получения настроек", все.... Вот теперь подумайте, может ли вам кто либо помочь, имея эту информацию? Думаю нет... Я сейчас включаю режим "ванги" и говорю вам, что вы непойми зачем, в asp.net впихнули Autofac как отдельный контейнер, не связанный со стандартным, так?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, да, я использую использую autofac взамен стандартному контейнеру

Comment: Зачем только... Ну, дело ваше. Вы его правильно подключили? Он имеет все стандартные зависимости? Контроллеры, сервисы, модули? Скажем так... Ваша задача с настройками, в стандартном ASP.NET решается в пару строк: 1. Прописываем в `appsettings.json` все необходимое. 2. Делаем класс, в который через конструктор передаем `IConfiguration`. 3. В нужном месте данного класса просим настройки через `объектКонфигурации[раздел:параметр]`. Ну и последнее, регистрируем в классе `Startup` этот класс (`services.AddTransient<SomeClass>();`), все. А Autofac, ну не знаю, смотрите сами, где накосячили)

Comment: https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/aspnetcore.html